# Sophisticated algorithms in biological systems

Tags: microbiology, systems-biology

I am looking for examples of (known) algorithms/data structures in biological systems. My current understanding is that these don't exist - or haven't been found - beyond a relatively low level of complexity, which would seem like strong evidence to me that evolution isn't able to come up with something as complicated (and multi-step) as, e.g., the Schönhage-Strassen algorithm.

I heard of Bloom filters for recognizing smells in fruit flies (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6304992/).

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about what you mean by "algorithms" or "data structures". Organismal morphogenesis could be looked at as an incredibly complex set of linked algorithms- people call it a "developmental program".

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of biological systems doing computation, according to my understanding:

1. Regulatory networks encode decision trees of significant complexity: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_regulatory_network).
2. Alan Turing did significant work on organismal morphogenesis showing how simple chemical patterns of inducers can lead to complex outcomes, "[Turing patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chemical_Basis_of_Morphogenesis)".
3. All of organismal development, cell division, etc. are tightly regulated procedures of gene regulation and morphogenesis.
4. The [inspiration for neural networks is brains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network).